# How this piece of code can be vulnerable in SQL-Injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I am auditing the following piece of code:

```
function getNormalizedLocationPath($path)
{
  $path = is_scalar($path) ? strtolower(trim($path)) : '';
  $path = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.]/', '', $path);

  return $path;
}

$path=getNormalizedLocationPath($_GET['path']);
$sql= "INSERT INTO paths VALUES (${path})";

$pdo = new PDO();
$pdo->query($sql);
```

As you can see it is an obvious SQL-injection vulnerable piece of code, but I will have trouble to prove it. How I can prove that this code is vulnerable to my supervisor?

Comment: Since only characters a-z, 0-9 and dots are left by that “sanitizing” function, I don’t see how there could be much damage done here. “Extending” SQL syntax beyond what was intended, usually requires the use of quotes, or braces, or at least spaces somewhere … Since no quotes are used _around_ the value, this query will of course only ever work for numeric values to begin with, anything else (with the exception of value keywords such as `null` mabye) would lead to a syntax error to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's possible that this code is safe.

I haven't thought about it much, to think about what edge cases could make it not safe. Like if you're using an old version of PHP in which `preg_replace()` doesn't understand unicode sequences or something. That could allow someone to encode a quote character in unicode, bypassing the regular expression filter. I don't know.

The reason it's not worth thinking about harder is that there's another solution that is even simpler to code, and is sure to be safe:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO paths VALUES (?)";

$pdo = new PDO();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [ $_GET['path'] ] );
```

By using a query parameter like this, the value of `$path` is kept separate from the query until after it has been prepared. So there's no way for the value to introduce errant quote characters or anything else that could affect the syntax of the SQL statement.

Therefore you have no neeed for a sanitizing function at all.* You can eliminate some code, which always makes a project easier to maintain.

You don't have to even ask this question, seeking expert help to determine if the sanitizing is fully safe.

---

* Not for the sake of SQL injection prevention at least. You might have a need to change the value for the sake of application features, but no matter what change you apply to that value, you won't have to worry about the SQL injection vulnerability if you use a query parameter.